# Unable to view column headers when read in data from Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I am reading in data from databricks using the following code:

```
acct = spark.read.csv("/mnt/syn/account/2018-06.csv", inferSchema = True, header=True)
```

However, I am unable to see the column headers

The printSchema() is as follows:

```
6d4cd0fe-dd7a-e811-a95c-00224800c9ff:string
5/19/2022 4:25:38 PM1:string
5/19/2022 4:25:38 PM2:string
0:string
14:string
_c5:string
_c6:string
_c7:string
18:string
_c9:string
_c10:string
_c11:string
71775000112:string
930580000:string
_c14:string
_c15:string
_c16:string
117:string
_c18:string
```

However, when I query the data as a table in Azure Synapse I get successfully get the headers as follows:

[image]

[image]

I'm pretty sure there is a simple explanation, but I can't think why this is case with Databricks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this Sample code.

```
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/export.csv"

df = spark.read.format("csv") \
  .option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .option("sep", ",") \
  .load(file_location)

display(df)
```

**Output**:

[image: Ref1]

for more detail **refer** this [**official**](https://databricks-prodcloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/7816483812338946/3672689341067908/5571463615735172/latest.html) document.

Comment: Hi Bhan, thanks again for reaching out. I didn't think it was as easy as you suggested .. need-less-to-say it didn't at all. I got the same result as shown in my original question

Comment: hi @Patterson, i done the repo on my env with sample example, I got header all details as shown in above image. please edit and provided code snippet and what error you are facing.